# Divergence/irregularity of alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was studying numerical series and was wondering if alternating series, so a series of form $\sum^\infty_{n=n_0}{(-1)^na_n}$, can be divergent or irregular or just irregular. In case there are both divergent and irregular alternating series, can someone provide an example?

- Note: by “irregular” I mean series that neither diverge or converge, so series for which the limit of the n-th partial sum doesn’t exist, for example $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n$, and by “divergent” I mean series for which the limit of the partial sums is $\infty$ with $+$ or $-$

Comment: What do you mean by "irregular"?

Comment: @lulu sorry, I explained it now, it was a bad translation from my native language

Comment: Ok, so why isn't that an example?  I guess it isn't clear what you mean by "divergent".  Are you restricting that term to series for which the limit of the partial sums exists but is $\pm \infty$?  In that case, you can't have both that and "irrelgularity".

Comment: @lulu yes, I know that in the same series you can’t have both, but I’m asking if there exist divergent alternating series, so for which the limit of the partial sums is $\infty$ (with $+$ or $-$) (as you said)

Comment: Sure.  Let $a_{2n}=10^n$ and $a_{2n+1}=10^{-n}$.  The idea being:  take a positive series which diverges and then, alternately, subtract off terms so small they have no impact on the divergence.

Comment: @lulu perfect thanks, that’s what I thought intuitively. If you want to, please post your answer so that i can mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The OP is interested in an example of an alternating series $\sum (-1)^na_n$, with $a_n≥0$ for all $n$, such that the limit of the partial sums is $+\infty$ (of course, reversing all the signs in such an example would give you an example with limit $-\infty$).

The idea behind such an example is to start with an obviously divergent positive series, like $\sum 10^n$, and then alternate it with very small terms (terms which have no impact on the limit).

An explicit example is $$  a_n =
\begin{cases}
10^n,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
10^{-n}, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$